# Mistakes in my landscape

Tags: rendering

I modeled a landscape by using a shrinkwrap modifier but my landscape has these kinda mistakes (see picture) how do I fix this?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: Select the whole thing in edit mode, then press M (merge), and select "by distance". You may also want to select _mesh > normals > recalculate outside_ from the menu at the top.